# Can I make vertical list of floating sharing icons responsive for different screen resolutions? (pic included)

Tags: css

I'm using addthis on one of my blogs.  I have their new option of a vertical floating list, and the code for the addthis buttons looks like this:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_floating_style addthis_32x32_style" style="left:0%;
top:15%;width:58px; margin:0 auto">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="box_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_send"></a> 
<a class="addthis_button_tweet" tw:count="none"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"     
g:plusone:annotation="none"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_reddit"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_stumbleupon"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
</div>
```

I have the feedback slide-out button set to top:70%. So the result looks like this in both screen resolutions:

[image: Overlapping iconds]

What I've tried:

I've tried using different types of things like height:auto; ... but nothing has worked yet.  The one issue is that the icons are 32x32, but I could probably make 'em smaller, if necessary.  Does anybody have an idea of how I can make this so it's responsive, and/or looks proper under all screen resolutions?  Any guidance in this regard would be **greatly** appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to put it in a container? If so you could set the `min-height` of that container.

Comment: hey Jason lemme know if my answer below is what u were looking for.. if you wanted a more direct answer specific to your question.. can you put it into jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi abbood.  Thank you for taking the time to answer!  I'm still working on a combination of your solution and the fiddle that dsundy provided.  Maybe I'm wrong in all this, but I just think the site I'm referring to ... http://www.wehaveissues.org ... has responsive issues on that left side ... perhaps it's the overall theme. But I did read up on the px/pt thing, and I understand .... 72 pt = 1 inch ... never knew that. I'll definitely mark it as resolved once I've figured everything out!  Thanks again for your time, abbood!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one should take caution from the idea of `one size design fits all resolutions` it's not that straight forward. however let me give you some pointers:

1. to design html/css that looks the same on multiple resolutions.. one should use two units:

   - `pt` for anything that is expected to have the same dimension on all resolutions.. ie let's say you are designing it for an old iphone with 150ppi and a retina one with 231ppi.. a pixel on a retina display is much smaller than it's counterpart in an iphone 3g.. and so if you put a margin of `5px`, it will look totally different amongst your different resolution targets. However, if you set a margin of 3 `pts`, then this is a physical metric you are setting  (think about it as an inch.. an inch is the same on any screen regardless of resolution right?) then in this case.. a `pt` does meet the `one size design fits all resolutions` principle
   - `px` for anything that is not scalable (ie a bitmap).. a bitmap is not expected to scale from one screen to another.. so you should use `px` in this case.. (`px` is a screen resolution specific unit of measurement).. but at the same time you **must** use different images for different resolutions.. so back when I worked at *amazon* we used a two different sprites for the *kindle touch* and *kindle paperwhite*, along with different `px` values for each.. but then we used pt for everything else. (the concept of `px` vs `pt` is a pretty dense one. i advise you to [read](http://dot5.drawar.com/posts/pt-vs-px) more about it. it took a while for it to sink me with me)
   - you can also use a clever mix of jQuery and css cascading (aka specificity) to use the same css base to address different targets.. please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14868902/766570) here.. we also did that at *amazon*
   - one thing you can look at (disclaimer: i only read about it but have no experience with it) [css mediatypes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp).. it allows you to make your css media specific (ie your css for a handheld will be different than that for print).. but i donno how much this overlaps with the idea of `one size design fits all resolutions`.. but i do know that we considered this idea at amazon but dismissed it as insufficient to meet our different resolution needs.

good luck!

Comment: Yes, abbood, thanks again for all that information!  It's a lot to soak in, but I now understand the difference between px and pt ... 72 pt = 1 inch.  And I understand the media screen / media print now, too ... and I'm really not even sure now if the site in question ... http://www.wehaveissues.org ... is actually responsive or if it isn't ... hehe ... I'll definitely keep working on it, though, and will hopefully resolve this soon. Thanks again for your time, and for all of the information, abbood!

Comment: Well, yes .. I just ended up learning more about media queries ... wasn't easy at first.  Properly configuring media queries into my .css worked out.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsundy/AALwW/1) that shows one way to achieve this.

The put the toolbox and feedback tag inside a container:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="addthis_toolbox"></div>
    <div class="feedback"></div>
</div>
```

Then with the CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 600px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px
}

.addthis_toolbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    width: 40px;
}

.feedback {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
}
```

Depending on whether or not you want it to scroll you can make the container `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`. Good luck!

#### Edit: Media Query for Screen Height:

Abbood brings up a good point with media queries. Here's an example of how you would use one:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 700px) {
    // CSS rules will be applied when the screen is < 700px tall.
}
```

Comment: Thank you dsundy .. for the information and for the fiddle. I'm fiddling around with it as I type ... hehe .. I'm reading up on the min-height and max-height attributes, and learning more how to use them.  I'll keep fiddling, though ... and once it's resolved, I'll mark it as such.  Thanks again for your time, dsundy!

Comment: No problem. I just added in a media query example to my answer. Have fun.

Comment: Can I use those media queries and just make the entire website fluid or responsive, dsundy?  I mean, just wrap the entire stylesheet around a media query and be done with it, instead of placing media queries everywhere?

Comment: Usually you have your regular styles and then, at the end of your stylesheet, multiple media queries for different breakpoints. These media queries then override the original styles that you made.